# Traffic Flow Data response description in documentation

Tags: here-api

I see examples with [flow data in documentation](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/traffic/topics_v6.1/example-flow.html), but I can't find what does means all it fields:

```
{
  "RWS": [
  {
    "RW": [
    {
      "FIS": [
      {
        "FI": [
        {
          "TMC": {
          "PC": 6467,
          "DE": "Gladenbach",
          "QD": "+",
          "LE": 12.52997
          },
          "CF": [
          {
            "SP": 55.2,
            "CN": 0.73,
            "TY": "TR",
            "JF": 0,
            "SU": 55.2,
            "FF": 52.6
          }
          ]
        }
        ]
      }
      ],
      "LI": "D01-06464",
      "DE": "L3048",
      "PBT": "2015-08-20T08:27:45Z",
      "mid": "ff3e7aab-eece-438c-818b-5920e4581330|"
    },
    {
      "FIS": [
      {
        "FI": [
        {
          "TMC": {
          "PC": 6468,
          "DE": "Fronhausen",
          "QD": "-",
          "LE": 12.55204
          },
          "CF": [
          {
            "SP": 56.95,
            "CN": 0.7,
            "TY": "TR",
            "JF": 0,
            "SU": 56.95,
            "FF": 53.6
          }
          ]
        }
        ]
      }
      ],
      "LI": "D01+06464",
      "DE": "L3048",
      "PBT": "2015-08-20T08:27:45Z",
      "mid": "77ede063-8d38-409a-a986-c8d91cdf3eb2|"
    }
    ],
    "TY": "TMC",
    "MAP_VERSION": "201503",
    "EBU_COUNTRY_CODE": "D",
    "EXTENDED_COUNTRY_CODE": "E0",
    "TABLE_ID": "1",
    "UNITS": "metric"
  }
  ],
  "MAP_VERSION": "",
  "CREATED_TIMESTAMP": "2015-08-20T08:27:43.000+0000",
  "VERSION": "3.1",
  "UNITS": "metric"
}
```

Where is this documents?

Comment: Can you share what return values come from https://traffic.cit.api.here.com/traffic/6.0/xsd/flow.xsd?app_id=xxx&app_code=yyy ???  I'm looking at this, but don't want to create an account yet until I know I can use it.

It's also a very bad design if you have to make a service call just to make sense of a service response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an XSD with description for that particular request
https://traffic.cit.api.here.com/traffic/6.0/xsd/flow.xsd?app_id=xxx&app_code=yyy
You can use your credentials to access it.

You can also obtain another XSDs for different types of request https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/traffic/topics/additional-parameters.html

Comment: Can you share what return values come from https://traffic.cit.api.here.com/traffic/6.0/xsd/flow.xsd?app_id=xxx&app_code=yyy ???  I'm looking at this, but don't want to create an account yet until I know I can use it.

It's also a very bad design if you have to make a service call just to make sense of a service response.

Comment: It's an xml file. You can just put that URL into your browser. I'm new to API's and searched an infinity on the Here Website for this info. Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there a known way to map NAVTEQ "Point TMC Location Code" to OSM road ID?